# Finding the confidence level and number of successes?

Tags: probability, statistics

Given that the sample size is $1500$ and the confidence interval of $p$ is $(0.050, 0.083)$. Find the confidence level and the number of successes.

I have so far that $E=Z_{1-\alpha/2}∗\sqrt{(p∗({p-1}))/n}$

Where $p$ is the center of the given interval, so $p = (0.050+0.083)/2 = 0.0665$

Also, the error $E$ as the difference of the midpoint and the endpoint of the interval so $E=0.0665-0.050=0.0165$

Plugging this into the equation I got that 
$0.0165=Z_{1-\alpha/2}*\sqrt{((0.0665)(1-0.0665))/1500}$

Solving for $Z_{1-\alpha/2}$ gives $Z_{1-\alpha/2}=2.56$ and since $Z_{2.96} = 0.99$

$Z_{1-\alpha/2} = 0.01$

Is what I have so far right? If so, how do I find the number of successes? Is it just to multiply 0.99 by the number of trials?

So that way I would get $1500*0.99=1485$ ?

Comment: Quick question, why is $p$ the center of the confidence interval?

Comment: I assume since the ends of the confidence intervals are $p \pm E$ ? I'm not certain though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $p = X/n,$ we have $X = np = 1500(.0665) = 99.75 \approx 100.$

To check everything, let's start from $n = 1500$ and $X = 100$ and
see what the formula for a 99% CI gives (when your derived values
are plugged in):

$$ p \pm 2.576\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}.$$

It becomes $(0.050, 0.083),$ which agrees with the initial 99% CI
(computations using R as a calculator below).

```
 x = 100; n = 1500; k = qnorm(.995); pm = c(-1,1); p = x/n; p
 ## 0.06666667
 p + pm*k*sqrt(p*(1-p)/n)
 ## 0.05007675 0.08325658
```

Note: This is supposing you are using the 'traditional' CI given
in the displayed expression above. A more accurate 'Agresti' (or
'Plus-4') interval uses $n^+ = n+4$ and $p^+ = (X + 2)/n^+$,
substituting $n^+$ for $n$ and $p^+$ for $p$ in the same
expression. However, the adjustment for the Agrest-style interval
is negligible when $n$ is a large as 1500. Also, the Agresti-style 
CI works best for 95% CI's.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! This was very helpful!